# Guice inject resolution with multiple implementation to type

Tags: guice

i have a situation where there two bindings with two different annotations for a type available

bind(MyType.class).annotatedWith(X.class).toInstance(XMyTypeImpl.class)
bind(MyType.class).annotatedWith(Y.class).toInstance(YMyTypeImpl.class)

I have another class which has dependency on MyType
@Inject
public Upstream(MyType myType) {}

without having annotation inside Upstream class, is it possible to get one of implementations of MyType.class get injected?

During bind, can i suggest to guice one of them is default for injection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add additional binding without annotation for your desired target value, e.g.:

```java
bind(MyType.class).to(XMyTypeImpl.class)
```